# Is Firefox 116 super slow or is just me?

Tags: firefox

I use Firefox on my M1 mac, it is at version 116, and I always have privacybadger, Ublock origin, and facebook container on. Since yesterday it has become intolerably slow (dialup internet slow) compared to Safari (which I do not like because I find I can leak less data online with firefox).

Is it just me? possibly, but I feel I need to make sure.  I did a fresh reinstall of firefox, but no dice.

Comment: Try turning off all those extensions (and others) to see if that helps. Alternatively, create a temporary user account and see if the slowness disappears. Lastly, make sure the extensions are updated as well.

Comment: actually there was ONE more extension that self updated yesterday -- PortAuthority, which causes the issue. Good call! Add some sort of 'go through the full list of add ons and check them' sort of answer and I'll accept it as correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is important to make sure, on a regular basis, that all extensions and add-ons are up to date, especially after browser updates. Some extensions may rely on operating system APIs which may change with updates, and some browser updates may change APIs as well. Some extension developers have a mechanism which alerts the user when updates are available, such as AdBlock and Ghostery. Some extensions also self-update, as you have found.